# Private git repo on (mt) gs

Tags: git, web-hosting, mediatemple

I would like to create a *private* git repository on mediatemple grid system hosting.

I followed this guide: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1594/Using+Git#gs it just works fine but basically anyone could clone my project. :D

If it is not possible is there any workaround with a 3rd party provider like https://bitbucket.org/?

Excuse me if this is a noob question, Im not a git expert.

Comment: Bitbucket provides private repo's for free. Why not use them?

Comment: I didn't really get it how to use just until now. I read this article http://markdotto.com/2011/11/02/how-to-deploy-sites-via-github/ and everything is clear as sky now. :))